# Python Combining two columns into one based on each columns value

Tags: python, data-structures

I am working from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction) dataset and I would like to combine yr_built and yr_renovated into one, preferably to yr_built, based on this: if the value in yr_renovated is bigger than 0, then I would like to have this value, otherwise the yr_built's value.

Can you please help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Why are you labeling your Question [tag:data-structures] - did you read the tag-description ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/data-structures/info )?

Comment: Happy Coding. SO is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing to your specification. Please go over [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and if you a specific questions, provide your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . If you encounter errors, copy and paste the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You basically need pandas for the dataframe, then create a new column using numpy to check if the value of `'yr_renovated'` is greater than zero else use `'yr_built'`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jonasyao/Machine-Learning-Specialization-University-of-Washington-/master/Regression/Assignment_four/kc_house_data.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df=df[['yr_built','yr_renovated','date','bedrooms']]
newdata['MyYear']=np.where(df['yr_renovated'] > 0,df['yr_renovated'],df['yr_built'])
newdata
```

[image]